# wp_query is empty in admin_init

Tags: wordpress

I'm developing a plugin and one of the issues I am running into is that I cannot get the post id within a function assigned to the admin_init hook.

I tried a few different methods; but, they all seem to use the $wp_query.

Below is a simple version the code I am using. I implemented the code like this just now and ran it by viewing the "post edit" page

```
add_action('admin_init','do_optional_featured_article');
function do_optional_featured_article()
{
    global $wp_query;
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($wp_query);
    echo "</pre>";
    die();
}
```

$wp_query is a mostly empty array, notably, the post member is empty

-- EDIT --

I got some advice over at wordpress.stackexchange  and added in this function:

```
function get_admin_post()
{
    if( isset($_GET['post']) ) 
    {
        $post_id = absint($_GET['post']); // Always sanitize
        $post = get_post( $post_id ); // Post Object, like in the Theme loop
        return $post;
    }
    elseif( isset($_POST['post_ID']) )
    {
        $post_id = absint($_POST['post_ID']); // Always sanitize
        $post = get_post( $post_id ); // Post Object, like in the Theme loop
        return $post;
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22753/earliest-hook-to-reliably-get-post-posts) will help. It states that the earliest action you can hook into, to get the global `$post/$posts` variables is the `wp` action. In the action hook [reference on the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference), you can see that the `wp` action executes a bit after `admin_init`, which is why you can't retrieve any posts there, I think.

So, that should work:

```
add_action('wp','do_optional_featured_article');
```

Comment: This just helped me out. Cheers